# No results when searching for Arabic string on Amazon Aurora

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have data inserted in the table with value `'7Learn سون لرن'`. But when I am trying to select:

```
CREATE TABLE sa_table ( name character varying(150) NOT NULL);
insert into sa_table values('7Learn سون لرن');
select * from sa_table where name like '7Learn سون لرن';
```

it's not giving results.

Dev - Rds Postgres (Giving result for same value and table)

Prod - Aurora Postgres (Not giving results)

SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING; -> UTF8 (Dev/Prod)

SHOW SERVER_ENCODING; -> UTF8 (Dev/Prod)

SHOW lc_collate; -> en_US.UTF-8 (Dev/Prod)

Please help what can be the more workarounds.

Comment: sounds like sql_ascii, can you add the ddl of the table and/or check the field collate?

Comment: added in the question.

Comment: Can you provide a complete test case, that is a sequence of SQL statements with which we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: added insert statement in question

Comment: Thanks. That works just fine for me. Can you show the result of `SELECT name::bytea FROM sa_table;`? Do you have an index on the column?

Comment: With copy & paste of your code, works for me  https://im.ge/i/PGOZ4

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Getting error ```invalid input syntax for type bytea``` after running the asked query. Yes, I have btree index on the column.

Comment: @FrankNStein I have added 3 commands in question which I used to replicate it.

Comment: It seems to be an Amazon-specific problem. With normal PostgreSQL, your statements work, as does the one I suggested in my  comment. Perhaps ask Amazon.

Comment: Can you run each query with psql from the same client just changing the -h ? If works the problem comes from the client, if not the problems is in the setting of the servers (just compare the pg_settings)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yeah to me also it seems to issue from the amazon side only.